# Reporting Service 2014 Service Pack 1 Failing to work with error - wrong database version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, upgrade, ssrs

Tonight we upgraded our SQL Server 2012 (SP2+CU6) cluster with SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1.

On that cluster nodes, we have Native mode Reporting Services scale-out configuration.

After in-place upgrade to SQL Server 2014 SP1, we got error from Reporting Services web page:

> The version of the report server database is either in a format that
>   is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The
>   expected version is '162'.

So there go question - why we have this error when we have upgraded to the most recent version of SQL Server 2014 and Service Pack 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two workarounds:

1. Delete one record from table ServerUpgradeHistory

> USE [name_of_you_SSRS_database]
>
> DELETE FROM ServerUpgradeHistory WHERE ServerVersion = 163

2. Install [Cumulative Update 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067839) for SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1. Before updating your SQL Server 2014 SP1 with Cumulative Update 1 - test it hard in your lab.

**BE AWARE** - Pay attention to backup encryption keys before you upgrade SSRS 2012 to
2014. After you apply CU1 all your encrypted content will be inaccessible.

Comment: we have a similar issue where it expects 147 and is finding version 162. However, when we delete the entries SSRS puts them right back in that table in under a minute.

Answer (score 0):

*There's a reason why the schema changed*; **deleting the record from the upgrade history should definitely not be the first resort.**  You should install the cumulative update.

The reason this may happen is that, for example, a cumulative update to `Service Pack 'x'` may include newer changes than `Service Pack 'x + 1'`.  So when you install `Service Pack 'x + 1'`, you may be missing those newer changes, and thus you may need a cumulative update for the new service pack.

This article is a good overview: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32360.sspr-troubleshooting-the-version-of-the-report-server-database-is-either-in-a-format-that-is-not-valid-or-it-cannot-be-read.aspx

The SQL server build number blog can help sort it out (http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)

For example, we had this problem when we installed SQL 2012 SP3: we had installed a cumulative update to SP2, then we got the Nov. 2016 security update -- so we had the "CU" version (note that there's two "security update for SQL 2012 SP2": the "GDR" version (if you don't have any CUs installed) and the "CU" version).

If you check out the build list, you see that that security update basically brought us up to SP2 CU14, which if you check the article above, brought us to Reporting Services Schema version 164.  So when SP3 was installed, we had "security update for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 **GDR**, which was based on an earlier version, that only had version 163.  So -- as per the article -- we needed to install SP3 CU5 or later to bring us back to the "164" schema version.